# How do you make the longer line of a two line title appear on the bottom and the shorter on top with CSS?

Tags: css

Is this possible or am I just thinking wishfully?

What I want to get away from:

> Title example here. It's a really long one, and I don't
>
> like it...

What I actually want the text to do:

> Title example
>
> here.  It's a really long one, and I hope it's possible.

I do know that I could split the title with PHP and insert a break, but if someone has a better solution that would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: No pure CSS soution would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can do this, but it's the same as using a conditional statement in PHP and it's putting resource work on the client. As PeeHaa said, no css can do this so it's your choice wether to do it client-side or server-side.